# how to get the name of the sub site in the designer workflow 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am creating a sharepoint 2010 workflow in sharepoint designer 2013.
How do i get the subsite name in a variable.
So far i could get the site url using workflow context - current siteurl

please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a direct way to retrieve the Title of a subsite using SPD2010 Workflow. But in SharePoint 2013 Workflow, you may use Web Service call using REST feature and get the subsite title using below REST endpoint url

```
https://webapp/teams/test/_api/web/webs?$select=Title&$Filter=(ServerRelativeUrl eq '/teams/test/subsite1')
```

Refer the below link how to use REST in SharePoint 2013 designer workflow

https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: Thank u for the reply but my workflow is a 2010 workflow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Upto my understanding there is no option in SPD2010 WF. Else you have to hardcode it.